# which power supply rating do I use for my diy led light panel?

Tags: led, diy

I'm building a led light panel using 24 x 18W SMD 5630 72LED Rigid Light Strip Tube Bar Lamp Bright White 12V 1800LM connected in parallel so whats the power supply rating

Specifications for each lights strip:

1. Key Features: LED Light
2. Light Source: 72 LED
   3.LED Size: SMD 5630
3. Luminous Flux: 1800LM
4. Output Power: 18W
5. Voltage: 12V
6. Light Color: White
7. Color Temperature: 6000K
8. Lifespan: 30000-50000 Hours
9. Material: PC & Aluminum
10. Dimensions: (100 x 1.8 x 1.5)cm / (39.37 x 0.71 x 0.59)" (L x W x H)
11. Weight: 6.7oz / 190g

Comment: Why don't you provide a link for the data sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Well, 24 x 18W = 432W.  Then 432W / 12V = 36A.

So you need a power supply rated 12V at a minimum of 36A.

That's one serious light panel you're creating.

Comment: or 24V 18A or 48V 9A etc. for series strings